# How to use PyInstaller to create an executable when VSCode is telling me "pyinstaller is not recognized"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using `PySimpleGUI` to create a `GUI` for a project. I have a directory that contains the `.py` file, as well as `images` I use in the `GUI`. I want to run this as an executable, so it is easier for me to transfer it between computers and I don't need to transfer all the different files every time.

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Isaac\code\eset419> pyinstaller --onefile main.py
pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pyinstaller --onefile main.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have confirmed that `PyInstaller` is installed via `pip install pyinstaller`. I am trying to run the `pyinstaller` command in the same directory in a python terminal as the `main.py` file.

I have tried looking in my `PATH` to see if there was an issue there, but I am not 100% sure exactly how to do that or where to look.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you install `pyinstaller`? Maybe you should use `/full/path/to/pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Comment: on Linux I can run it also using `python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py` (with upper `P` and `I` in `PyInstaller`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual environment like venv, you can ensure that it is present in PATH by activating and printing the PATH variable using `echo $PATH`. This will show you a colon separated string that should include something like:
`C:\Users\Isaac\code\eset419\.venv/Scripts`. If that is not the case, it means that the virtual environment is not active.

If you are not using a virtual environment, then it is possible that python is not in your $PATH variable.
You can also try locating pyinstaller by using `pip show pyinstaller` and then adding that location to `$PATH`